# Regex Matching bigger String first

Tags: regex

I am trying to match this string:

```
www.abcdgbs.com/p/Flights/abcd
```

with regex

```
regex = ".*(/Hotels|(/p)?/Flights).*";
```

pipe separated for matching from multiple regex

I want to get the index where this string is matching (15 in above case)
my code is

```
String test = "www.abcdgbs.com/p/Flights/abcd";
String regex = ".*(/Hotels|(/p)?/Flights).*";
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = patt.matcher(test);
System.out.println(m.find() ? m.start(1) : -1);
```

It is ignoring /p and matching from Flights giving me index as 17,
I want this to first match with bigger string i.e. `/p/Flights` first and give index as 15.

I want to use same regex for matching **www.abcdgbs.com/Flights/abcd** as well.

Comment: Java? Please use URI instead.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `.*` from your regex and match the text that you want:

```
String regex = "(/Hotels|(/p)?/Flights)";
```

With greedy `.*` in your regex before these keywords, regex engine is attempting to match longest string before any of those keywords as your `(/p)?` is optional.

**So with `.*` your first captured group is `/Flights` but with `.*` removed your first captured group is `/p/Flights`.**

You will get `15` printed now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my extended version:

```
(?:(?:(?P<PROTOCOL>https?):)?//)?(?P<DOMAIN>.+?)/(?P<PREFIX>p/)?(?P<TYPE>Flights|Hotels)(?P<SUFFIX>/.+)?
```

See in colors here: https://regex101.com/r/wD7aR7/2